# Are active listeners a good solution to populate UI changes once a day?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fetch

Using Cloud Firestore as a database for my application.

The labels/images I use in the app are **updated about once a day**, if that, and are populated from the data saved onto my Firestore database.

I'm trying to weigh the pros of having a one-stop solution to my having my UI updated automagically and not having to deal with unreliable network on the user's behalf, and the cons of my application being a drain on both, the user's battery life and their data connection.

There are no documentations I can find on this, and the only source I have  is [this Firecast video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aoxOtMM2rc) where I can find some confirmation for the former use case.

I'm trying to figure out if I should go with manual fetches or active listeners.
If someone know about any documentation on this topic, I'd be thankful for it.

Comment: This video you refer to is probably the most detailed documentation you can find and it seems it answers your questions. What is not clear enough? On which topic you still have questions?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec the issue is that resources/answers/documentations that talk about the use of active listeners talk about use cases where there needs to be constant fetching. For instance, a stock market app where the stock prices change constantly. 
I want to know about having an active listener in an app which needs to be updated merely once a day.

Comment: IMHO what is explained in the video is valid for a once-a-day update: the updates do not need to be frequent. The question is more "Are your users going to keep the app opened for an entire day"? (I mean without [detaching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) the listener)